# How to rewrite SASS ampersand in Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, tailwind-css

Hi I am rewriting the CSS [slideshow](https://codepen.io/davywaiyn-the-sasster/details/ExLELaZ) from SASS into tailwind. So far so good.
But when it comes to the ampersand then I am stuck.

What I basically did is i took the following SASS:

```
&--hero {
    z-index: 3;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    height: 85%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) skewY(-10deg);
    transform-origin: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
```

And did rewrite it into:

```
<div className="z-30 left-0 top-2/4 h-85/1 -translate-y-2/4 -skew-y-12 origin-center shadow-sm"> </div>
```

However unfortunately I cannot achieve the same effect. I am working down from top to bottom rewriting it step by step and the wirst two CSS classes (wrapframes and slideshow) I managed to rewrite successfully. But the next one "slideshow slideshow--hero" I am not sure how to rewrite with the ampersand. As my attempts are not working.

```
<div className="relative h-screen h-screen overflow-hidden">
  <div className="position-absolute top-0 left-2/4 w-full h-full translate-x-0">
    <div className="slideshow slideshow--hero">
      <div className="mainslides">
        <div className="slide slide1"></div>
        <div className="slide slide2"></div>
        <div className="slide slide3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="slideshow slideshow--contrast slideshow--contrast--before">
      <div className="secondslides">
        <div className="slide slide1"></div>
        <div className="slide slide2"></div>
        <div className="slide slide3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="slideshow slideshow--contrast slideshow--contrast--after">
      <div className="thirdslides">
        <div className="slide slide1"></div>
        <div className="slide slide2"></div>
        <div className="slide slide3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help or tips please?